# Set any type from WSDL in Zeep SOAP request

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

### I have WSDL envelope like this:

```
...
<xs:complexType name="hilfsmittelattribute">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://hma.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd" processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...
```

### What I would like to do is something like this

```
conn = zeep.Client(...)
data = {
    ....
    'hilfsmittelattribute': {'koerperhaelfte': 1}
    ...
}
pack = conn.service.someMethod(**data)
```

but I get error that

```
TypeError: ... got an unexpected keyword argument 'koerperhaelfte'. Signature: `_value_1: ANY[]`
```

I read documentation from here [Zeep documentation for Any](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html#any-objects)

## But:

if I do:

conn.get_element('ns0:hilfsmittelattribute') # or ns1, ns2, ns3...

I get

```
LookupError: No element 'hilfsmittelattribute' in namespace http://ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd. Available elements are:  -
```

But if I write

```
hilfsmittelattribute_type = conn.get_type('ns2:hilfsmittelattribute')
```

I get the type object

( the code return )

```
hilfsmittelattribute_type.elements
>> [('_value_1', <Any(name=None)>)]
```

but if I would like to use this type object like this

```
hilfsmittelattribute_ = xsd.AnyObject(
    hilfsmittelattribute_type, hilfsmittelattribute_type(koerperhaelfte='1'))
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: {...}hilfsmittelattribute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'koerperhaelfte'. Signature: `_value_1: ANY[]`
```

---

EDIT:

I try to create SOAP envelope by hand. If I set :

```
....
<hilfsmittelattribute>
    <koerperhaelfte>5</koerperhaelfte>
</hilfsmittelattribute>
....
```

It actually works... So the problem needs to be in Zeep on handling Any type.

Comment: Can you share WSDL's URL? It will help to understand your problem.

Comment: https://azhtrial.noventi.healthcare/services/test/BswSchnittstelle2?wsdl

Comment: I think you want to call
'retrieveHmaDefinition(asXsd: xsd:boolean, kostentraegerik: xsd:string, hilfsmittelposnr: xsd:string)'. If correct what is three input parameter values (asXsd, kostentraegerik and hilfsmittelposnr)?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I know. The parameter is called  koerperhaelfte. The problem is that because it is a any parameter, the zeep can’t handle it. Or I don’t know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has still trouble with this...

The fix is to create custom `etree` element

```
import lxml.etree as ET
koerperhaelfte_element = ET.Element("koerperhaelfte")
koerperhaelfte_element.text = "rechts"
```

and then use it inside json

```
'hilfsmittelattribute': {
      "_value_1": [koerperhaelfte_element],
},
```